# How do "scalar" PHP arrays work under the hood?

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

## Background

I ran into a problem this week with an interesting root cause. The problem was with how PHP arrays work. I had an API endpoint that was using **array_filter**, and sometimes returning a JSON Object, sometimes a JSON array. Here's some examples:

```php
json_encode([0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3])
```

returns the string

```
"[1,2,3]"
```

However, the following code:

```php
json_encode([0 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3])
```

returns the string:

```
"{"0":1,"2":2,"3":3}"
```

## My Question

What is PHP doing under the hood for "scalar" (non-map) arrays?

Say I have an array of

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Is that, in essence, "shorthand" for this:

```
[0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3]
```

Lastly, how does `json_encode` ever return a JSON array, instead of a JSON object? Does it have business logic inside of it that goes something like:

IF:

- Index starts at 0
- Indexes end at LENGTH - 1
- Indexes are ordered least to greatest
- The difference between two neighboring indexes is always 1

?

Will [This PHP 8.0 RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/negative_array_index) be potentially disruptive for JSON serializers?

Comment: Your first example doesn't need to keep track of the array keys because they are numerical and sequential, your second example needs to keep track of them because they are not sequential. The answer to your question "_Is that, in essence, "shorthand" ..._" is yes. `json_encode()` should never return either an array nor an object, it returns a string.

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica Sorry, to clarify I meant a JSON object (within the string). I'll edit the question. This comment would 100% work as an answer btw, you hit everything

Comment: If you need to always return a JSON array, use `array_values()` before encoding. PHP treats sparse arrays as associative, so will always produce an object when converting to JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take your first example and compare it to your second example

```
json_encode([0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3]); //returns "[1,2,3]"
//versus
json_encode([0 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3]); //returns "{"0":1,"2":2,"3":3}"
```

The resulting JSON string is different because in your first example the returned string does not need to keep track of the array keys. This is because they are numerical and sequential.

In your second example, the keys are *not* sequential, so the resulting JSON string needs to keep track of the keys so that they can be decoded properly.

`[1, 2, 3]` is equal to `[0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3]`. The only difference is explicitly stating the keys, which is not necessary and is done automatically when no keys are specified. (Will always be sequential and numerical)

Also, `json_encode()` should never return either an array nor an object, it returns a string. In a comment you clarify that you meant "JSON Object", but I think that premise is flawed because it doesn't ever return a PHP array, it *always returns a JSON object*. The complexity of the resulting string does not change that it is a JSON object.

As [Miken32 noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58845167/how-do-scalar-php-arrays-work-under-the-hood/58845302#comment103964077_58845167), if you always want the return to be less complex (ignoring keys), you can use `array_values()` before encoding. PHP treats sparse arrays as associative, so it will always produce an object when converting to JSON.